# Magic Mouse 2 and Magic Trackpad 2 are recognized as Mighty Mouse

Tags: macos, trackpad, mouse, magic-trackpad

Just got a new Magic Keyboard, Magic Mouse 2 and Magic Trackpad in the mail.

I am running OS X El Capitan; plugged them in and everything was fine. However they are not recognized as "Magic" devices.

**Can't scroll, no gestures are working**.

I can't even scroll, only move cursor, click and right click. The devices are just detected as regular peripherals.

I also have the Magic Mouse 1 and Magic Trackpad 1 lying around: they work just fine. The keyboard is ok too.

Here are screenshots for the Mouse Settings on my Mac:

[image: Mouse gestures setting in System Preference]
[image: Generic mouse settings being shown]

Any ideas?

In fact **both** the mouse and trackpad are recognized as the old Apple Mighty Mouse. This is what I see when connecting any of the devices:

[image: Notification showing Apple Mighty Mouse connected]

**Things I've tried**

- Deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mouse / trackpad`
- Resetting PRAM
- Resetting SMC
- Logging as a Guest user
- Creating new location in Networking
- Re-pairing both with and without cable

It always comes back as Mighty Mouse. First generation devices do work without a hitch. When both mice/trackpads are connected, preference pane shows gestures for Magic Mouse or Trackpad but only 1st gen devices work.

Answer (score 5):

After fiddling with it for a while I came to the conclusion that I need a software update.

Installing **OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 Beta (15C27e)** fixed the issue.

Got to say force touch is pretty sweet.